# Windows option not enabled when creating new Flutter Project for Windows Development

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

I am trying to create a new Flutter Project for Windows Development but I am unable to check the Windows check box in the `Platforms` section of Android Studio. I am using the Latest Flutter SDK (Stable) and Visual Studio (2022 Community) is also installed.
Please help me find what is missing.

### Issue:

[image]

### Flutter Doctor:

[image]

Comment: Please look at https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run below command to enable windows.

```dart
flutter config --enable-windows-desktop
```